# Apache subdomains, folders and rewrite rules

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I've been trying to setup the following with no success.

I'd like `/WebContent/<any-folder-name>/html/index.html` to accessible by `http://<any-folder-name>.homelan.net`. Basically homelan.net is a local domain, with wildcards enabled pointing to the same IP address. I've been trying with different RewriteRules but with no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily use [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) to map the host names to a certain document root on your server.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Apache URL Rewriting Guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html). The example under Virtual User Hosts sounds like exactly what you are trying to do.